# anacron fails to run rkhunter each day

Tags: apache-2.2, cron, rkhunter

I put a rkhunter script in daily.cron  on Apache Centos 7.

When I manually run the script, it works fine. but leaving it in daily.cron it fails to run.

I get this email every day instead.

```
/etc/cron.daily/rkhunter:

/etc/cron.daily/rkhunter: line 3: rkhunter: command not found
```

if you look in cron.daily you see a rkhunter script.  inside that script this is the contents.

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT=`rkhunter --update --cronjob --report-warnings-only --nocolors --skip-keypress`

if [ "$OUTPUT" != "" ]
 then
echo $OUTPUT | mail -s "[rkhunter] Warnings found for $(hostname)" email@example.com
fi
```

if i manually run

```
sh rkhunter
```

from that directory it works.
I tried to have a file extension on it rkhunter.sh but it was the same result so with or without the .sh extension i am not sure it makes a difference.

How can I get this script to run daily and not fail with command not found.

Comment: Is your script calling itself in its own script? Is it script inception (inscription o_O)? This line: `OUTPUT=\`rkhunter --update --cronjob --report-warnings-only --nocolors --skip-keypress\`` calls program "rkhunter" that is not found. Try changing it to absolute path.

Comment: **cron runs your command in a restricted environment.**
...
Of particular note is the PATH is restricted to `/bin:/usr/bin`. The vast majority of *"my cron script doesn't work"* problems are caused by this restrictive path. If your command is in a different location you can solve this in a couple of ways: ... *provide the full path to `/path/to/rkhunter`*

Comment: full path worked @HBruijn

Answer (score 0):

Edit your crontab entry like so, as user that's supposed to run script:

```
# crontab -e
```

Add this line:

```
@daily /path/to/script.sh
```

Write and quit (press <kbd>:wq</kbd>:

```
:wq
```

Remove script from /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter.